# How do I send string interpolation from my Model to my ViewController to download JSON on Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, string-interpolation

I have a text view which I type an IP address into which sends it to my Model/IpManager which successfully prints the correct format IP address to the console.  I now want to send this IP address back to the `viewcontroller` so that it can be used to download JSON data and populate a `tableview`.  I have been unable to do this. Below is my `viewcontroller` and Model/IpManager.

There is still the code in there that was a hard entered IP address which I used to prove it works and populates the `tableview`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var users = [User]()
        
    @IBOutlet weak var ipTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var ipManager = IpManager()
    
    final let url = URL(string: "http://**.***.**.**:*****/userconfig")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        ipTextField.delegate = self
        
        downloadJSON()
    }
    
    @IBAction func ipSearchPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        ipTextField.endEditing(true)
        //print(ipTextField.text!)
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        ipTextField.endEditing(true)
        //print(ipTextField.text!)
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.text != "" {
            return true
        } else {
            textField.placeholder = "Enter IP"
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let ip = ipTextField.text {
            ipManager.fetchComms(ipAddress: ip)
            //ipTextField.text = ""
        }
    }    

    func downloadJSON() {
        guard let downloadURL =  url else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                //print("Trouble!")
                return
        }
        print("Success!")
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedComms = try decoder.decode(Users.self, from: data)
                self.users = downloadedComms.users
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommCell") as? CommCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        cell.nameLbl.text = users[indexPath.row].username
        cell.DOBLbl.text = users[indexPath.row].online
        
        return cell
    }
}

import Foundation

struct IpManager {
    
    let commsURL1 = "http://"
    let commsURL2 = "/userconfig"
    
    func fetchComms(ipAddress: String) {
        let urlString = "\(commsURL1)\(ipAddress)\(commsURL2)"
        print(urlString)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, your `IpManager.fetchComms` should use `URLComponents` to construct a URL from mutiple parts. Then, just return that URL and pass it to the `downloadJSON` function as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I am pretty new to this and am struggling with how to actually pass the URL to the downloadJSON function as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

First, you could improve your `IpManager` to use the `URLComponents` instead of manipulating the strings by yourself. The `fetchComms` will then return the created `URL` or `nil` if the input is invalid:

```
struct IpManager {
    
    let commsURL1 = "http"
    let commsURL2 = "/userconfig"
    
    func fetchComms(ipAddress: String) -> URL? {
        var comp = URLComponents()
        comp.scheme = commsURL1
        comp.host = ipAddress
        comp.path = commsURL2
        
        let url = comp.url
        print (url ?? "Invalid URL")
        return url
    }
}
```

Then, remove the `final let url`

Then, remove `downloadJSON()` from `viewDidLoad()` and put it into `textFieldDidEndEditing` instead:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   if let ipString = ipTextField.text,
      let url = ipManager.fetchComms(ipAddress: ipString) {
        downloadJson(url)
   }
}
```

Lastly:

```
func downloadJSON(downloadURL:URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask ( // .......
    //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, that is really helpful.